# What type of rich response google uses to display flight info in the assistant

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

I am trying to create a similar rich response to what google provides for the flight status and was wondering what kind of rich response they use to display this fancy formatting? Is that just a dynamically generated image? Thanks.
[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7SSp.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think The card/response in the above image are custom cards built by google, Maybe there is no option to replicate those once unless you work with Google, But as of now the only responses/cards you can build are [here.](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/responses#top_of_page)

Comment: I think you are right. It’s a bit anti-competitive but what’s new, it’s google.